# JPA not deleting single row

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have now spent the last couple days trying to identify why there is an issue with deleting a single row.  I am bewildered by this issues since I am not provided with any errors!  Things I am certain of, 1) There is one data row in the Postgres DB.  I have hardcoded the primary key in which it needs to delete.

**User Registration Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "registration")
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    UserRegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public void registerUser(@RequestBody UserInformation accountInfo) {
        // Perform some back validation.
        registrationService.createUserInformation(accountInfo);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/register/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer userId) {
        // Delete the registration account
        registrationService.deleteUserInformation(userId);
    }
}
```

**User Registration Service**

```
@Service
public class UserRegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    UserInformationRepository userInformationRepository;

    /**
     * Accepts a user's registration and attempts to save it to the database.
     * @param info
     */
    public void createUserInformation(UserInformation info) {
        userInformationRepository.save(info);
    }

    public void deleteUserInformation(Integer userId) {
        UserInformation user = userInformationRepository.findById(userId).get();
        userInformationRepository.delete(user);
//        userInformationRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
}
```

**User Information Repository**

There are no custom method signatures.

**UserInformation Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
public class UserInformation {

    @Id
    @Generated(value = "GenerationType.AUTO")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = PersonalInfo.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "personal_info")
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String emailAddress;

+ Setters and Getters
}
```

**PersonalInfo Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personal_info")
public class PersonalInfo {
    @Id
    @Generated(value="GenerationType.AUTO")
    @Column(name = "info_id")
    private int infoId;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private States state;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "home_number")
    private String homeNumber;

    @Column(name = "work_number")
    private String workNumber;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "personalInfo", orphanRemoval = true)
    private UserInformation user;

+ Setters and Getters
}
```

**States Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="states")
public class States {

    @Id
    //@Generated(value="GenerationType.AUTO")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="abbrev")
    private String abbreviation;

    @Column(name="state_name")
    private String stateName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state")
    private List<PersonalInfo> personalInfos;

    + Setters and Getters
}
```

I originally tried using deleteById but it didn't seem to do anything.  I have a feeling it's something really obvious that I'm missing.

**Updates:**
I have changed the data type on the "id" value from int to Integer on the UserInformation model.  When I run my delete test with this change the record is deleted.  However, then I am unable to insert records.  It appears there is an issue with respect to the datatype and how the Postgres  database handles it.  Has anyone experienced this kind of problem?

Stacktrace when inserting with datatype of Integer

```
at com.deck.grocerymanager.Integration.RegistrationTest.userRegTest(RegistrationTest.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
```

Comment: Are you able to find user here when you try to find it by id ?

Comment: Try changing Id type to `Integer`. There is only a slight chance it solves this propblem, but at least it will prevent some future problems.

Comment: Thanks Selindek!  That was the problem.  I guess all JPA DB column models need to have non-primitive datatypes.  I would have never thought to look at that